# Counting the times a value in a vector is different per combination of 4 other vectors

Tags: r

This is what my dataframe looks like:

```
a <- c(1,1,4,4,5)
b <- c(1,2,3,3,5)
c <- c(1,4,4,4,5)
d <- c(2,2,4,4,5)
e <- c(1,5,3,2,5)

df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
```

I'd like to write something that returns all unique instances of vectors a,b,c,d that have a different value in vector e.

For example:

```
  a b c d e 
1 1 1 1 2 1 
2 1 2 4 2 5 
3 4 3 4 4 3 
4 4 3 4 4 2 
5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Rows 3 and 4 are exactly the same till vector d (having a combination of 4344) so only one instance of those should be returned, but they have 2 different values in vector e. I would want to get a count on those - so the combination of 4344 has 2 different values in vector e.

The expected output would tell me how many times a certain combination such as 4344 had different values in vector e. So in this case it would be something like:

```
a b c d   e
4 3 4 4   2
```

So far I have something like this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  unite(key_abcd, a, b, c, d) %>%
  count(key_abcd, e)
```

But this will count the times e has been repeated per combination of a,b,c,d. I would like to instead count the times e is different per combination of a,b,c,d.

NOTE: There are both repeated combinations of values in vectors a,b,c,d and repeated values in vector e. I would like to return only the count of unique values in e for unique combinations of a,b,c,d.

Comment: there is. My other question asked for repeated values in e, this one asks for different values in e. Maybe you should read the titles of questions better before marking posts as duplicates.

Comment: @RichardScriven - notice how the dataframes in both questions are different. In the first question the combination 4344 has 2 same values in e "3" and "3". In this dataframe the combination 4344 has 2 different values in e, "2" and "3". In my situation, both repeated and different values in e mean completely different things that I'd like to analyze. You aren't helping much

Answer (score 2):

You could try adding a little `dplyr` on:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  unite(key_abcd, a, b, c, d) %>%
  group_by(key_abcd) %>%
  summarise(e = n()) %>%
  filter(e>1)
```

Comment: just executed the query! In the meanwhile, small question: something I did not mention in my question is that there are some repeated records of the combinations of the values in vectors a,b,c,d. What would you add to this to only get the count of different values in vector e for the distinct combinations of the values in vectors a,b,c,d?

Comment: Maybe `df %>% distinct %>% count(a, b, c, d) %>% filter(n > 1)`  ?

Comment: There are are also repeated values in vector e for each unique combination of values in  a,b,c,d. How would I only get the count of unique values in e for each unique combination of a,b,c,d?

Comment: Hi jeremycg. Would you know then how I could avoid getting duplicates from vectors abcd as well as duplicates for vector e that correspond to each combination in abcd?

Comment: I think this would do the job but not sure: `df %>%
  unite(key_abcd, a, b, c, d) %>%
  group_by(key_abcd) %>%
  summarise(e = n_distinct(e)) %>%
  filter(e>1)`